# Replace the last occurence of a character in a file

Tags: linux, awk

I have this AWK script which replaces every form feed character (0x0C, 12) with 5 new line characters:

```
f=${*:-"-"}
awk 'BEGIN {FF=sprintf("%c",12); LF=sprintf("\n\n\n\n\n")}
     {i1=0;for(i2=i1+1;i2<=length($0);i2++) if(substr($0,i2,1) == FF)
     {print substr($0,i1+1,i2-i1-1) LF;  i1=i2}
      print substr($0,i1+1,length($0)-i1)}' $f
```

Now what I want to do is replace **only the last occurence** of this symbol in the file. Cannot think of a straightforward solution. How do I detect the last line? Any ideas?

AWK is preferable (performance issues).

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/\f/!b;:a;$!N;/\n.*\f/{h;s/\n[^\n]*$//p;s/^.*\n//;};$!ba;s/^\(.*\)\f/\1\n\n\n\n\n/' inputfile
```

Explanation:

- `/\f/!b` - If the line doesn't include a FF, branch to the end and print it
- `:a` - Label "a"

  - `$!N` - If it's not the last line, then append the next line
  - `/\n.*\f/{` - If there's a FF in the newly appended line, then

    - `h` - Save the accumulated lines in hold space
    - `s/\n[^\n]*$//p` - Delete the last accumulated line and print the rest
    - `g` - Restore the accumulated lines from hold space
    - `s/^.*\n//` - Delete everything except the last accumulated line
  - `}` - End if
  - `$!ba` - If it's not the last line, branch to label "a"
- `s/^\(.*\)\f/\1\n\n\n\n\n/` - Replace the last FF in the file with five newlines

Note that this works even if the last FF is not on the last line.

Here's how to do it in AWK:

```
awk '/\f/ {
         print accum;
         accum = $0;
         next
     }
     {
         accum = accum "\n" $0
     }
     END {
         match(accum, ".*\f");
         print substr(accum, 1, RLENGTH - 1) "\n\n\n\n\n" substr(accum, RLENGTH + 1)}'
     }' inputfile
```

It only keeps in memory what it must.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `awk` enough to do this, but it's possible with `sed`:

```
sed -e '$s/\x0C$/\x0C\x0C\x0C\x0C\x0C/' your_file
```

`\x0C` stands for character with ascii hex code 0C as you probably have guessed.

If you want to modify your file on the file, instead of dumping the result of the script to the stdout, add `-i` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perl one-liner that reads the entire contents into memory and replaces the last carriage return:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{\r([^\r]*)\z}{\n\n\n\n\n\1}' "$f"
```

or

```
perl -0777 -pe '
  $pos = rindex($_, "\r"); 
  substr($_, $pos, 1) = "\n\n\n\n\n" if $pos != -1
' "$f"
```